# Java EE auto completion

Tags: java, glassfish, java-ee-6

Where can I find the jar file or the source code of JEE6? Or is there another way how you can get autocompletion for this in Netbeans/Eclipse?

And I have just installed glassfish so that i can use JAX-RS but i do not understand how it works. Why does the javacompiler find these classes but netbeans does not? I building with maven2 but have not set any paths or so.

And why am I not able to install JEE6 without glassfish? I just do not need an application server for a REST service with Jersey.

Best regards,
CQQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question #1**: 
See [this](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/samples/helloworld-webapp/1.7/helloworld-webapp-1.7-project.zip) example project.

The example project is built with maven, which may answer your question about auto-complete.  Netbeans 6.8+ (approx) has built-in maven support.  After the first build of the example project, I think you'll see that auto-complete works better for any dependencies (i.e. jersey) inside the pom.xml.  In my Netbeans, auto-complete works, but the javadocs are not there, which may mean that Jersey wasn't bundled with them.

**Question #2**: Your maven on the command line and the one inside Netbeans are different copies.  You can make Netbeans use a specific copy of maven in Tools/Options/Misc/Maven/External Maven Home.  This may clear up some confusion.

**Question #3**: Jersey can run in [Tomcat](http://blog.spaceprogram.com/2008/01/getting-started-with-jax-rs-and-jersey.html) or [Jetty](http://wikis.sun.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21725365) if you find Glassfish to be too much app server for your needs.